# PHP: add elements id as hash to Facebook share link

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, hash

On **[this page](http://urbansunsets.com/radio-shows/u-can-read/)** I have a bunch of mp3 files displayed as nicely styled boxes.

Each box has a Facebook share button. I would like to add each boxes id `(mp3jWrap_0, mp3jWrap_1`, etc) as hash to its **Facebook share link** so that every time a shared item is visited from Facebook, the URL contains the *item's hash*.

For this purpose I have written the code:

```
<?php
  $actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $actual_link = trim($actual_link, '/');
    $actual_link = $actual_link . '#mp3jWrap_' . $id;
   echo '<li class="fb_share"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u="' . $actual_link . '" title="Share on Facebook" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>';
?>
```

The problem: the string after the hash (with hash included) is not in the URL when you click the *share button*. Why?

Comment: remove / before hash and try it.

Comment: Just did it. Nothing changed.

Comment: _“Why?”_ - because you neglected to apply proper URL encoding.

Comment: Can you please provide details on _proper URL encoding_? Thank you!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+url+encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to pass the `$actual_link` trough the `urlencode()` PHP function.
So, your code should look like this:

```
echo '<li class="fb_share"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u="' . urlencode($actual_link) . '" title="Share on Facebook" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>';
```

This is happening because the browser will think that the hash is intended for the share page(the one on fb) not on the shared link.

Without the urlencode, the share URL would be:

`http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://example.com/path/#mp3jWrap_id`

With it encoded:

`http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fpath%2F%23mp3jWrap_id`

And this would finally be interpreted as an ok link.

Answer (score 0):

You have to **urlencode** $actual_link